# Removing SDK's from "Copy Bundle Resources"?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app ready for review and I encountered a problem while trying to upload the archive to iTunes Connect. The problem I encountered is similar to this. Xcode keeps telling me 'error processing symbols' I followed the comments and advice and removed adMob and mediation SDK folders from "Copy Bundle Resources" under Build Phases and the upload succeeded.

Question is - Is it safe to remove those SDK's? Will admob still work on my app if I removed them from "Copy Bundle Resources"?

Comment: Best way to determine that is to build the app and run it on an iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using external library or Framework then it should be going to Frameworks and not in "Copy bundle Resources". You can add one by going to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html

Comment: Yes I did Link Binary with Libraries. But these framework folders automatically appeared in "Copy Bundle Resources" . I did not manually add them. I deleted them and just wanted to know if it was safe

Comment: Basically its not a intended behavior for library. Any library/Framework added to "Link Binary with Libraries" will convert the library to binary while packaging the application. While "Copy Bundle Resources" contains mostly of your project images and XIB/Storyboard which are copied into the app.